# Numpy Arrays based on threshold criteria from a list

Tags: python, numpy

I need to take a list with 7000 elements, the values range from ~ -150 to 150, and it cycles back and forth. Every time the value crosses a threshold of -50 I need to include all the values in an array until it crosses -50 again. I need to make an array for each of these cycles and then count how many arrays are made and find the mean of how many elements each of these arrays has.

Comment: Giving a small exampke would help us understand better..

Comment: Lets say I have an array [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], I want to split it so that each time I come back to 1 I make a new smaller array e.g 3 arrays would be made, each [1,2,3] , [1,2,3], [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code 1) calculates the indices where the next element crosses -50, 2) splits the array at elements that crossed -50, 3) counts how many arrays there are after splitting, and 4) calculates the mean of each split.

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.array([...])
crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(array + 50)))[0]
splits = np.split(array, crossings + 1)
count = len(splits)
means = [x.mean() for x in splits]
```

Comment: Thank you! Could I also ask, what could I add that it only counts and splits at -50 if the number before it was larger than negative 50? i.e if the number before is -48 then it splits but if the number before is -52 then it does not split?

Comment: The data looks like this a wave, and I am trying to bin each wavelength starting at the -50 mark. Right now have the bins treat the second -50 encountered as a crossing, while I need every second -50 to be treated as a crossing. I hope that makes sense, This code outside the loop does this manually ```Sniff_1 = np.append(splits[2], splits[3])```

Comment: @DominicDemeterfi, are you referring to scenarios where there are -50 values in the array? My solution above treats these as crossings. If that's not what you're referring to, but rather you're interested in which direction the crossing is coming from, `crossings` can be modified accordingly so that splits will only start after -50 is crossed from above:
```crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(array + 50)) < 0)[0]```

Comment: Also, I am interested in the average of how many items are put in each bin, not the average of the values within the bin. Is there a way to do that as well? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: The average items per bin can be calculated manually, `sum(x.size for x in splits) / len(splits)`, or with a Numpy function, `np.mean([x.size for x in splits])`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!